# Docker API questions

Tags: api, docker

I have a distributed application to be containerized. (will have multi containers on multi hosts).
I would use docker(or maybe orchestrator) API in my program running inside container, to monitor container events.
There are many container orchestration toos, I'm not sure what tool will I have in different customers, so if possible I would like to avoid orchestrator locked-in.
Now I have some questions:

1. I tried "curl http://10.69.117.136:4243/events" on shell to monitor event, but I can't capture any event (I used docker stop to stop one container in this host). I'm sure docke API is working, e.g. I can get images, containers, or even evnets with since=..
   Any idea why I can't get any event?
2. I want to use "group of containers" as a logical functional unit. It seems there is no such object in API spec. Will this be supported in future?
   (k8s pod fit well, but as I said I'd avoid locked in)
3. Is it possible to use cluster API and meanwhile avoid orchestrator locked-in?
   Here (http://blog.docker.com/tag/libswarm/ ) mentioned libswarm is for such purpose if I understand it (Thanks to libswarm...now they won’t) correctly. 
   But it seems now libswarm is renamed to swarm, which itself is an orchestrator alternative? I mean if customer use other orchestrator (e.g. LMKTFY, marathon) then there will be no swarm API, right?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest that these questions should be asked in the Docker official issue tracker.

Comment: OK, I will ask there, thank you.